# Node-Red Pm2 Setup

Tags: javascript, iot, pm2, node-red

I am trying to start my node-red on a raspberry pi 2 using pm2. I am using the startup command:

```
pm2 start /usr/bin/node-red-pi --node-args="--max-old-space-size=128" -- -v
```

At first it seems to work:

[image: NodeRed Startup pm2]

But unfortunatly then it errors:

[image: NodeRed Error pm2]

Thats the log:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
at Module._compile (module.js:373:25)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:404:10)
at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
at Function._load (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2/node_modules/pmx/lib/transaction.js:62:21)
at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2/lib/ProcessContainerFork.js:28:21)
at Module._compile (module.js:397:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:404:10)
at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
```

Comment: Did you solve the problem?

Comment: I'm also having this issue. Were you able to fix it?

Comment: hi - not with "node-red-pi". what I did was to reset overclocking on my pi - no overclocking anymore and I startet node-red with the normal "node-red" command in pm2. the pi is running now for 2 months without any problems. have to say that only node-red is running on this machine so I don't care about the RAM usage....

Comment: Same problem in windows x64 with node-red, pm2 tries to start and after about 15 successful reattmpts cannot do it so gives up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please make sure you installed the latest PM2 version (>2.x):

```
$ npm install pm2@latest -g
$ pm2 update
```

Then start node-red again, it should works as expected:

```
pm2 start node-red --node-args="--max-old-space-size=128" -- -v
```